# What is the difference between " as string" and "stringvalue" in swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift, typecasting-operator

I have a code :

```
var i : AnyObject!
i = 10
println(i as String)
println(i.stringValue)
```

> it get crashed on `as String` line but runs in second `i.stringValue`.

What is the difference between as `String` and `stringValue` in the above lines?

Answer (score 10):

`.stringValue` is a way to extract Integer into string value but `as String` will not work for that And if you use `as String` then Xcode will force you to add `!` with `as` which is not good and it will never succeed and it would crash your app. you can't cast `Int` to `String`. It will always fail. Thats why when you do `as! String` it crashes the app.

So casting is not a good idea here.

And here is some more ways to extract Integer into string value:

```
let i : Int = 5 // 5

let firstWay = i.description // "5"
let anotherWay = "\(i)"      // "5"
let thirdWay = String(i)     // "5"
```

Here you can not use `let forthway = i.stringValue` because Int Doesn't have member named `stringValue`

But you can do same thing with `anyObject` as shown below:

```
let i : AnyObject = 5 // 5

let firstWay = i.description // "5"
let anotherWay = "\(i)"      // "5"
let thirdWay = String(i)     // "5"
let forthway = i.stringValue // "5"  // now this will work.
```

Answer (score 2):

Both are casting an Int to String but this will not work anymore.
In Swift 2 its not possible to do it like that.

U should use:

```
let i = 5
print(String(format: "%i", i))
```

This will specifically write the int value as a String

Answer (score 1):

with `as String`, you can not cast the value but you define that the variable contains `String` but in you case it is `Int`.so it crashes.

while the other way i.e. of `i.stringValue` cast your value into `String`.So it doesn't gives you any crash and successfully cast into String value.

> Note: As you are using `AnyObject`, variable have member `stringvalue`...but Int doesn't have...To cast Int value check out @Dharmesh Kheni answer