# UISearchBar and JSON Data

Tags: json, swift, uisearchbar

This is my first time using a UISearchBar and it is proving to confuse me.

I think my biggest problem here is not understanding how JSON is stored and displayed.

I have my JSON data stored as:

```
    [{
  "referralId" : "v-1519014616",
  "name" : "Empire State Building",
  "storeId" : "",
  "hereNow" : {
    "count" : 2,
    "summary" : "2 people are here",
    "groups" : [
      {
        "count" : 2,
        "type" : "others",
        "name" : "Other people here",
        "items" : [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "stats" : {
    "tipCount" : 1105,
    "checkinsCount" : 185916,
    "usersCount" : 129661
  },
  "venueRatingBlacklisted" : true,
  "beenHere" : {
    "lastCheckinExpiredAt" : 0
  },
  "specials" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "items" : [

    ]
  },
  "venuePage" : {
    "id" : "64514349"
  },
  "verified" : true,
  "location" : {
    "state" : "NY",
    "neighborhood" : "Midtown Manhattan, New York, NY",
    "crossStreet" : "btwn 33rd & 34th St",
    "lat" : 40.748469532965927,
    "address" : "350 5th Ave",
    "cc" : "US",
    "city" : "New York",
    "postalCode" : "10118",
    "formattedAddress" : [
      "350 5th Ave (btwn 33rd & 34th St)",
      "New York, NY 10118"
    ],
    "lng" : -73.985513794430119,
    "distance" : 17,
    "country" : "United States"
  },
  "hasPerk" : false,
  "id" : "43695300f964a5208c291fe3",
  "categories" : [
    {
... etc
},
```

I have this stored in an array titled locations and I am trying to filter through it with a search bar.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let name = self.locations[0]["name"].string
        filteredLocations = locations.filter { names in
            return (name!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Now, obviously, `name` is only going to search for the item in the array. How would I be able to filter through every location's `name` key to properly filter?

Comment: Nobody even knows what self.locations is or what it looks like if it were an array storing dictionary objects.

Comment: @ElTomato its stored as an ArrayValue - does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this one** ... don't take name first from location array...

```
 let filterArr = locations.filter {
        return (($0["name"] as! String).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())))
    }
```

use this one to get the search result

Comment: This works.

I have a few questions if you don't mind.

Firstly: Why does it let you call $0["name"] but not locations["name"]?

Second: I changed it to $0["name"].stringValue is this any different than explicitly calling it as a String?

I greatly appreciate your help here. @pradeep

Comment: locations["name"].. you can't access array of dictionary like this means without index value ...and second one is $0["name"].stringValue u can read from here u will get to know why...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837053/what-is-the-difference-between-as-string-and-stringvalue-in-swift